# How can I monitor both metrics and log messages on same dashboard?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, grafana, influxdb, chronograf

Right now I use Grafana and Chronograf with InfluxDB. But I also want to show the logs of my application.

I tried using Loki, but it only works on explore and can't be used on a dashboard. Do you know if this is possible currently?

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of one of the built-in dashboards for Apache HTTP: In the top half you have metrics (like which URLs where most often accessed) and at the bottom you can see the raw log event(s).

[image]

Comment: So you have Elasticsearch, Kibana, and filebeat working?

Comment: Yes. But thanks to [ECS](https://github.com/elastic/ecs) the fields are unified across the stack, so as long as the timestamps match up you could add Metricbeat,... visualizations and filter everything on the same field (eg a specific Docker image,...)

Answer (score 0):

Current version of Loki allows viewing both Metrics and Logs in the single dashboard.
Please refer the screenshot. Left side is "Metrics" and right side is "Logs" (underlined in blue).
You can click on "Split" button and get the Split view.
[image]